# Can this Elasticsearch query be optimized?

Tags: elasticsearch

```
{"query":
  {"filtered":
    {"filter":
      {"or":
        [{"term":{"id_admin":255}},{"term":{"id_user":255}}]
      },
    "query":
      {"bool":
        {"must":
          [{"match":{"striped":"sentence"}}]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Query returns entry where `id_admin` or `id_user` is 255 and `striped` = sentence.**

We use 2.3.1 version.

Can this query be more optimized?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ES 2.3.1, the correct way to write this query is as follows:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "id_admin": 255
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "id_user": 255
          }
        }
      ],
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "striped": "sentence"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: On average, in the same environment, my query is faster than yours.

Comment: All I'm saying is that the DSL syntax you're using [is deprecated](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/breaking_20_query_dsl_changes.html#_literal_filtered_literal_query_and_literal_query_literal_filter_deprecated) and my query is the equivalent one that you should be using with ES 2.x onwards. Now regarding performance, I reckon you have load tested both queries a few thousand times in order to claim that yours is faster or you're just making one-off calls using curl or head or sense and checking the `took` time (which doesn't mean much)?